# My handleOpenURL implementation on Android won't work, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm working on a PhoneGap project and I'm trying to implement a simple mechanism to call the `handleOpenURL` method (as per this example: http://goo.gl/FKmFL) when a URL is passed to the app. Sadly I've run into a few stumbling blocks. The problem is two fold:

**Firstly** my call to `sendJavascript` didn't seem to work at all - no call to the JavaScript, no error, nothing. I have read that this function doesn't work on activity start but no one else seems to be having trouble...

**Secondly** when I call `loadUrl` (see the example below) I get an error message as follows:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: handleOpenURL at undefined:1
```

Below is my Java code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    final Intent intent = getIntent();

    Log.d("myApp","Start");
    Log.d("myApp","Data string: " + intent.getDataString());

    if(intent.getDataString() != "" && intent.getDataString() != null) {

        Log.d("myApp","Calling handleOpenURL");         
        String url = intent.getDataString();
        // this.sendJavascript("handleOpenURL(\"" + url +"\");");
        super.loadUrl("javascript:handleOpenURL('"+url+"')");
    }
}
```

Below is my JavaScript code:

```
<script>    
    function handleOpenURL(url) {
    $("body").append("<h2>Url:</h2>");
    $("body").append("<p>"+url+"</p>");
}
</script>
```

Any help you can offer would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: I would recommend instead of 'if(intent.getDataString() != "" && intent.getDataString() != null)', that you use !TextUtils.isEmpty(intent.getDataString()). This performs both the null check and is it not empty calls for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip jimmithy! I actually went to change it earlier today but realised `String.IsNullOrEmpty` doesn't exist in Java (I'm a C# developer) so I just left it.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly this problem on Android w/ DroidGap...

The first time the application is started, the intent data is visible to the DroidGap subclass methods, however there is no way to get the data into the Javascript execution environment such that it's usable.

I tried a sendJavascript call (as shown above), but I suspect this fails because the page hasn't finished loading and onDeviceReady hasn't yet fired.

I also tried setting a cookie in CookieManager, but couldn't quite get that to work.

Appending the data to the query string i.e.
super.loadURL("file://..." + "#" + url)

And then parsing location.href in an onDeviceReady event handler works the best.  It doesn't work the very first time the app is started, however it does work after that when the app is closed+killed and then started.

Its too bad InvokeString doesn't work on Android and that it's been deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've recently moved to using PhoneGap Build and I believe their GenericPush plugin support should handle this - haven't had chance to look at it though!

Answer (score -1):

First, one minor point, your check for 'intent.getDataString() != ""' isn't going to be reliable. It needs to be '!intent.getDataString().equals("")'.

I don't see a call to "setJavaScriptEnabled(true)", which seems to be a minimum requirement to get this to work.

You might try finding a working tutorial for this kind of thing and then start including the elements relevant to your application.

Comment: This is a PhoneGap project thus my activity inherits from `DroidGap` which handles the WebView (and enables JavaScript). Sorry I should have made that more clear! I'll update my question accordingly. I've had a look at a couple of tutorials but had little joy so far.